# edit time extracted from excel in python

Tags: python, excel

i can't make changes(to increase seconds) to the existing date time extracted from excel sheet.

```
Code:
import xlrd
import xlwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('sample.xls')
wb2 = xlrd.open_workbook('sample2.xls')
# Load XLRD Excel Reader

sheetname = wb.sheet_names() #Read for XCL Sheet names
sh1 = wb.sheet_by_index(0) #Login
sheetname2 = wb2.sheet_names() #Read for XCL Sheet names
sh2 = wb2.sheet_by_index(0) #Login

def readRows():
    #a = datetime.time(10, 23)
    #print a
    for rownum in range(sh1.nrows):
        rows = sh1.row_values(rownum)
        for rownum2 in range(sh2.nrows):
            rows2 = sh2.row_values(rownum2)
            date = rows[0]
            date2 = rows2[0]
            print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date,0)
            print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date2,0)
            #date2 = rows2[0]
            if date == date2 :
                #print 'found'
                time = rows[2]
                time2 = rows2[2]
                if time == time2 :
                    print 'time matched'
                    #remaining code
                elif(time<time2)&&(time+datetime.timedelta(0,15)>time2)):
                    print 'less'
                    ti=xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(time,0)
                    ti2=xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(time2,0)
                    print ti,ti2 # shows (2013,11,11,10,42,36) 
                    print a.time #not working
                    ti+=datetime.timedelta(seconds=3) #not working
                    ti2+=2 #not working
                    print ti,ti2
                    print time
                    time=datetime.datetime (xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(time,0)) + datetime.timedelta(0,1) #not working
                    time2 = xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(datetime.datetime(time2),0)+ datetime.timedelta(0,1) #not working
                    print (xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(time+timedelta(seconds=3),0)),(xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(time2+timedelta(seconds=3),0)) #not working
                elif (time > time2) & (time+datetime.timedelta(0,15) > time2)) :
                    print 'more'
                    print time,time2
print readRows()
input('enter to exit:')
```

I have two log files. One has log for every 15 seconds and other has log for variable time. Therefore i need to map the closest value of the second log to the time in the first log for that I am not able to make changes to the extracted time from the excel sheets but the time is shown properly and compared properly too.

Comment: afaik you cant modify ... you need to open a worksheet to save and then populate it with the modified data ... not sure I understood your question properly

Comment: i mean in single cell i have yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss in excel which is getting displayed properly, but to be able to compare i need to add seconds to the time of these cells to check the relative value from the first excel sheet which i am not able to do.

Comment: I still dont really understand the problem ... xlrd.xldate_as_tuple does or does not return the right value?assuming it does, you then need to take that tuple and convert it to a datetime object.  then you can add a timedelta to it...

Comment: xlrd.xldate_as_tuple returns proper value..As i am new to python can you please guide me how to convert it to datetime object and add timedelta to it because i have already tried it and it doesn't work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you may need to change the order of the tuple returned by xldate_as_tuple or change the month to be one based instead of zero based... but basically once you have got your date seperated into its parts just make a datetime object from it and add the timedelta ...

```
>>> year,month,day,hour,second = 2002,10,15,22,23  #oct 15 2002 @ 10.23pm
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,second)
>>> num_seconds = 3600 #one hour
>>> time_delt = datetime.timedelta(seconds=num_seconds)
>>> print d1+time_delt
2002-10-15 23:23:00
>>> #notice it is an hour later!
```

The python documentation can be very helpful

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my doubt is when i fetch values from excel sheet and print it using "print xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date,0)",the output is "(2013,3,1,12,16,9)" to which i am not able to add datetime.timedelta